# Adding a new column using transform in ddply in R

Tags: r, plyr

I am working with a data set where vehicle IDs repeat over time. An example of a single vehicle is something like below:

```
df <- data.frame(veh = rep(2,15), lane=c(rep(3,5), rep(4,5), rep(5,5)), frame=1:15)
```

I wanted to add a new column in which 'yes' meant that there was a change in lane and "." meant no lane change. I used ddply as below:

```
> ddply(df, 'veh', transform,change=c(NA,ifelse(diff(df$lane)!=0,"yes","." )))
   veh lane frame change
1    2    3     1   <NA>
2    2    3     2      .
3    2    3     3      .
4    2    3     4      .
5    2    3     5      .
6    2    4     6    yes
7    2    4     7      .
8    2    4     8      .
9    2    4     9      .
10   2    4    10      .
11   2    5    11    yes
12   2    5    12      .
13   2    5    13      .
14   2    5    14      .
15   2    5    15      .
```

This gave me the desired output. However, in my original data set, there are many more  vehicle IDs ('veh' in df). The first vehicle id '14' is repeated 455 times and total number of rows are 23454. When I use the same function for original data set I get following error:

```
> hv1 <- ddply(hv, 'Vehicle.ID', transform,change=c(NA,ifelse(diff(hv$Lane)!=0,"yes","." )))
Error in data.frame(list(Vehicle.ID = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 455, 23454
```

Note that 'hv' is the name of my original data set. Could you please point out the problem in the code?

Comment: get rid of `hv$`; otherwise `transform` will try to insert the entire column from your data frame, instead of the piece it is given as the first argument by `ddply`.

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks! Removing hv$ fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `ddply` for this, since it is a simple vector problem. Try using `diff` and simple indexing:

```
do.call('rbind', lapply(split(df, df$veh), function(z){
    z$change <- c(NA, diff(z$lane))
    z$change[z$change==1]<-'yes'
    z$change[z$change==0]<-'.'
}))
```

Result:

```
> df
   veh lane frame change
1    2    3     1   <NA>
2    2    3     2      .
3    2    3     3      .
4    2    3     4      .
5    2    3     5      .
6    2    4     6    yes
7    2    4     7      .
8    2    4     8      .
9    2    4     9      .
10   2    4    10      .
11   2    5    11    yes
12   2    5    12      .
13   2    5    13      .
14   2    5    14      .
15   2    5    15      .
```

Comment: I think the issue is there are multiple cars, so you need some sort of splitting by car (either with `ave`, which is what I would do here, or with the plyr/data.table/dplyr packages).  I could be misunderstanding though. +1 anyway to get you to 10k ;)

Comment: Because of multiple cars I did need splitting and that's why used ddply. Thanks anyway.